# how to unpack after npm pack?

Tags: node.js, npm

You have a npm package that was packed into a `tgz` tarball.

This, apparently, is done with [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack).

However, how can you *unpack* it? There's no such thing as `npm unpack`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done with `npm install tgz_file.tgz --production` command.

It will install that package, along with all of its dependencies, in the path relative to where the command was ran from.

Comment: yeah I am looking to unpack to the NPM cache directory manually

Answer (score 3):

You can call the following command to unzip the package: `tar -xzf YOUR_NPM_PACKAGE.tgz`.

It's going to produce a folder called `package` in the directory you called the command.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I would also note that it will overwrite the `package` folder if you execute the commands for different versions of the packed `tgz` file. I looked but couldn't find (quickly) how to set the output path with the option, so I ended up making different subfolders for each version I wanted and pathing up via `../YOUR_NPM_PACKAGE.tgz`.